# Firebase high priority message when app is on foreground

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM messages on my android project. I have read this info on developer page;

High priority messages on Android are meant for time sensitive, user visible content, and should result in user-facing notifications. If FCM detects a pattern in which messages do not result in user-facing notifications, your messages may be deprioritized to normal priority.

I just want know , must we show user-facing notifications even if app is on foreground?  if we do not show notification when app is on foreground (any activity is visible) May it cause any deprioritization?

Comment: hi, is there any solution for this question

Comment: Hi, I am not sure but when I searched , we must show a notification whenever a push message received. it is necessary to user must see a message arrived from firebase